# How to read a local (res/raw) file line by line?

Tags: android, file, readline, filereader

I have a text file in my res/raw directory. I want to read the file line by line, but FileReader and BufferedReader fail, because of Android's security restriction. How else can I do it?

Comment: How did you figured out it fails for security reasons? Post your code

Comment: Standard Java file access [FileReader] throws a FileNotFoundException for local files. It works for files stored on the SD, however.
http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/working-with-files-t115.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getResources().openRawResource()` returns an `InputStream` that should be usable for line-by-line reading.

Comment: Inputstream inp = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
Call me stupid, but this has the methods read() [which reads a single byte], read(bytes[]) [which reads n bytes] and read(byte[], int offset, int length). No readLine()!

Comment: @Vinay: `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.textfile)))`

Answer (score 2):

A DataInputStream allows you to do a readLine (along with a host of other operations); see
[DataInputStream Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html).