# How to return [search] result as file location?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working on Search able Dictionary. It uses SQLite database. Dictionary formats are like below (2 column separated by "-")

```
Apple - One kind of fruit
Cricket - One type of game
Titanic - One type of Movie
```

Here `Apple` is column `A` and `One kind of fruit` is column `B`

I've updated my database like below

```
Apple - res/raw/Apple.txt
Titanic- res/raw/Titanic.txt
```

I want to open `Apple.txt` file and show text when user search `Apple`. But the sample code i'm using is made for TextView only, not to open file, buffer and ViewText.

Here is my code which shows Column B on my application

```
TextView details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
details.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Please suggest how can i open Apple.txt from search query by replacing above code?

[post Updated]

Comment: Why not just store file paths in column B?

Comment: Why using files when you already have the texts in the database?

Comment: @Egor thank you very much for you reply. Could you plz explain how can i put file path that can be open able by app to view txt?? your answer seems helpful to me!

Comment: @Ridcully Actually I'm developing a drug database and want to put drug instruction manual on .txt file for each drug. I've tried to put that directly into database but it takes too much space and making such database is also painful.

Comment: Your question sounded like you'd have the described table already. If that's not the case and you have the instruction manuals already as text files, go with Egor's suggestion and save the file paths in column B.

Comment: @Egor I've update my post. Please put your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Ridcully I want your help to solve this problem [post updated]

Comment: Tanzil, you cannot expect people here to do your work. Simple googling brings up e.g. this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219150/how-to-read-a-local-res-raw-file-line-by-line that describes how to read text from res/raw. If you're a total newbie to Android, I'd suggest that you start with  some simpler programs to learn the basics of the Android system before starting a complex project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split according to `-`:

```
String[] res = line.split("\\s+-\\s+");
```

Now you'll have something like:

```
[Apple, One kind of fruit]
```

Now, because you have `Apple` in column A, you know that you have to show the location of `apple.txt`.

Alternatively (a better approach), you can store the path in column B as @Egor stated in the comments:

```
Apple - the_path_to_open.txt
```

And now, when you split, you'll get the path in the **1** element of the array (Which is column B) and you can open it to show its' results.

Comment: There is no need to over complicate it. `line.split("-")` will work fine.

Comment: No, this will include spaces and he'll have to remove leading whitespaces after the split. The split I wrote is more general, and you can have many spaces as you wish between the first and second column.

Comment: I'm gonna try it and will feedback after that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I'm taking Alternative approach you've suggested above. Could you please solve the code i'm stacked now {I've updated post]? It'll be so helpful for me to learn from a experienced programmer like you. :)