# Read csv from res/raw folder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android Studio / Kotlin and would like to implement a simple quiz app as a test project.

For this I have stored a csv file under `res/raw` and now want to read the file in a class. However, I can only find solutions that use the relative path (`res/main/res/raw/question.csv`) and would like a nice solution that uses the identifier `R.raw.question`.

There must be a simple solution for this, which I just can't find right now, right?

Comment: Google: read file from raw resource. You could better place the file in assets folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219270/115145

Comment: @blackapps a raw resource is a very good place and you can read easily like pointed out by CommonsWare. The advantage of the raw folder ist that you can use localization and other things that the res folder offers

Comment: Okay, it's indeed just that simple. I have a class QuestionManager in which I can access the resource id but not the resources themselves. Within the activity it works without problems, thanks!